# knockout With binding is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to do simplistic behavior using knockout inbuild WITH Binding. There is UL-LI list  which is bound with ViewModel using ko.applyBinding. working fine.
Now, I am trying to implement select item behavior with list. Thus implemented selectPatient behavior inside the ViewModel and bind it with LI tag using Click. The method is called and observable selectedPatient variable is set.

Now there is a div inside the parent div at the same level of UL-LI, I am trying to bind with selectedPatient using With. Not Working.

Code for Reference:

```
<div data-role="content" id="MyPatientDiv">
        <div>
            <ul data-bind="foreach:Patients">
                            <li data-bind="click:$root.selectPatient">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="javascript:" id="pName" sortorder="none"><span data-bind="text:LastName"></span>
                                                ,<span data-bind="text:$data.FirstName"></span></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="javascript:" id="pid" sortorder="none"><span data-bind="text:$data.DisplayId">
                                            </span></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="javascript:" id="pLocation" sortorder="none"><span data-bind="text:$data.UnitName">
                                            </span></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="dlgAction" databind="with:selectedPatient">
            What would you like to do for <span databind="text:$data.LastName"></span>,<span databind="text:$data.FirstName"></span>
        </div>
    </div>​
```

Script Code:

```
function PatientsModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.Patients = ko.observableArray([]);

    if (data.patientEncounters == null) self.Patients([]);
    else self.Patients(data);

    self.selectedPatient = ko.observable(null);

    self.selectPatient = function(data, target) {
        self.selectedPatient(data);

        //$('#dlgAction').dialog('open');
    };
}

MyPatientList = {
    PatientsModel: null,
    DOMElementId: 'MyPatientDiv'
}

$(function(){
    var data = [{
        AccountId: null,
        AdmissionStatus: 1
        AttendingPhysicians: null,
        BedId: null,
        DisplayId: "32456",
        EncounterKey: "00000000000000000000000000000003",
        FirstName: "John",
        Gender: null,
        LastName: "Rambo",
        LocalPatient: true,
        MiddleName: null,
        MyPatient: true,
        PatientId: null,
        PatientKey: "00000000000000000000000000000003",
        RoomName: null,
        SameName: false,
        TemporaryPatient: false,
        UnitName: "IC1",
        VisitId: null}];

        data[0].LastName;

    MyPatientList.PatientsModel = new PatientsModel(data);
    ko.applyBindings(MyPatientList.PatientsModel, $('#MyPatientDiv')[0]);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Regards
Sumeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed dashes in `data-bind` keyword:

```
<div id="dlgAction" data-bind="with:selectedPatient">
    What would you like to do for <span data-bind="text:$data.LastName"></span>,
    <span data-bind="text:$data.FirstName"></span>
</div>
```

Also you don't have to put $data into `data-bind` attribute you could just specify properties names:

```
<div id="dlgAction" data-bind="with:selectedPatient">
    What would you like to do for <span data-bind="text: LastName"></span>,
    <span data-bind="text: FirstName"></span>
</div>
```

EDIT: It works for me. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/BjeP9/

There was mistake in data - you missed coma after `AdmissionStatus` property. Also you tried to load `data.patientEncounters` that is always null so your collection wasn't initialized.

Comment: I found it was a typo while copying the code ( the - signs). And still its not working for me :(

Comment: I added this <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>, and still found it empty.

Comment: Ok I will try to put it on JSFiddle